# How to have more than one instance of the kubernetes service object itself?

Tags: kubernetes

Is it possible to have more than one instance of the actual `Service` object created in deployments that actually manages the access to pods (containers) and what happens if the actual service object itself is somehow deleted or destroyed?

This is the service object specified in a deployment YAML file:

```yaml
kind: Service
apiVersion: v1
metadata:
  name: my-service
spec:
  selector:
    app: MyApp
  ports:
  - protocol: TCP
    port: 80
    targetPort: 9376
```

Comment: In your example you're defining a default service type `ClusterIP` so it's basically a set of iptables rules. You can have more than one service targeting the same pods - if that's what you're asking. Service objects are independent of pods, so when you delete a (ClusterIP) Service object nothing else disappears.

Comment: If you'd specify what do you want to achieve it would be easier to post an answer. Literally the answer is "yes" (assuming different name), but I'm guessing it's not much of a help. Also, please take a look at: https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/service/

Answer (score 2):

The Service object only exists as an abstraction within the Kubernetes API. The actual implementation is distributed across your entire cluster, generally in the form of iptables rules created by kube-proxy on every node.